# Graphics in an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, graphics, arraylist, jpanel

I am trying to create a code that prints 10 random graphics (oval,rectangle etc).
I'm hopping to do this by adding my random ovals etc in an ArrayList and then let Java randomly pick a shape 10 times from this ArrayList and print these picked items.

Now I have no idea if this is even possible and how I would go about this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cara extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Random random = new Random();
    //...s

    public Cara() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300)); // make panel 400 by 300 pixels.
        // ... 
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    protected class RandomShapesComponent extends JComponent{
    @Override

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 

        super.paintComponent(g);     // clears the background
        // ...
    }
    }

    /**
     * redraws the Cara JPanel, when the button is pressed. *
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        regenerate();
        repaint();
    }

    private void regenerate() {
        // clear the shapes list
        //...

        // create random shapes 
        // ... 
    }


    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        final Cara cara = new Cara();    
        // create the GUI on the event thread.
        // this is better than 
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Computer Assisted Random Artist");
                frame.add(cara, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                JButton button = new JButton("redraw");
                button.addActionListener(cara);
                frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                cara.regenerate(); // can be done here if cara has a size!
                frame.setVisible(true);                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And below is a way for me to draw a triangle (this is one of the shapes i would like to put into the array and be randomly picked):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Tri extends Cara{
 public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
// create random variables for collor and shape of triangle
int x;
int y;
int x2;
int y2;

x = (int) Math.random()*100;
y = (int) Math.random()*100;
x2 = (int) Math.random()*100; 
y2 = (int) Math.random()*100;

int r1;
int g1;
int b1;
r1 = (int) Math.random()*255;
g1 = (int) Math.random()*255;
b1 = (int) Math.random()*255;
 Color color = new Color(r1,g1,b1);
 //draw triangle

 g.setColor(color);
 g.drawLine(x,y,y2,y);
 g.setColor(color);
 g.drawLine(x,y,y2,y2);
 g.setColor(color);
 g.drawLine(y2,y,y2,y2);


} 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible.  Here's an idea:

- Have an abstract base class called "Shape" and it has a method called "draw()" which has a parameter for a Graphics context
- Have subclasses of Shape for Triangle, Circle, etc and fill in each's draw() method accordingly
- Have an ArrayList instance variable in FruitPanel
- in the FruitPanel constructor initialize the ArrayList with 10 Shape subclass objects
- From your paintComponent() method in FruitPanel call draw(g) on each of the things in your ArrayList

You can figure out the randomization and such yourself... this is a basic structure.  Good luck!

Comment: Hello thanks for the advice however i have trouble understanding some of your points (the abstract class one and how to fill in the draw methods. I also would like to note that i have edited my code because my fruitpanel code was kinda inrelevant

Comment: HI Damhuls, An abstract class is a concept you can Google to better understand.  The base class does not need to be abstract, you could also just have a fairly blank draw() method that is overridden by the subclasses.  The draw methods will be similar to how you are currently drawing your triangle, they will just draw the appropriate shape.  Checkout this resource: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs5/lectures/0502/0502.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a service object which will draw a shape in the panel according to the number passed 1 to 10. It will have 10 methods which will draw different shapes.

Then when you want to draw any of the shapes- generate a random number less than 11 and use that number to call your service object to draw the respective shape.

Comment: Or evens simpler, just have a random int, do a switch on the int, and then have respective code for each shape, all in the paintComponent(), no need for a separate object.

Comment: @davecom A separate object would provide extensibility without having to modify the base code - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer See my other answer... this answer was the best quick and dirty way to do it, the other was the right way, in my opinion.

Comment: @davecom I might have misunderstood the this answer and your comment ;)